# What's the fastest way to append to a list with Numba?

Tags: python, list, append, numba, jit

I'm creating some code that does a lot of list appends. It has to be performant so I'm using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to `@jit` compile it.

I've checked the [Numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#list) on lists, but it doesn't give much information on the best way to append to them.

Should I use the `list1 + list2` notation, or should I used `list1.append(value)`?

Comment: I think it would help to show us what you're actually doing. I don't think we can really answer this without knowing more. Your `list1 + list2` and `list1.append(value)` don't even do the same thing, it's completely unclear why you're comparing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list1 + list2` creates a new list which is rather slow. In-place operations like `list1.append(value)` should be faster, but the iterative resize can make it not so fast if you use this in a loop. You can directly add a list to another in-place quickly with `list1.extend(list2)`.

Lists are actually rather slow; even in Numba (AFAIK due to checking instructions being generated and the multiple resize doing allocations+copies). If you know the list size is bounded, then you can use an array with the maximum possible size (as long as it is reasonable), fill it progressively (using an increasing index), and then either make a copy of the part used or just return a view of it. On mainstream platforms, allocating data in virtual memory does not directly map it on physical memory. This means a large allocated array take (almost) no space in physical memory and page are only allocated when you write into it (the size of the pages is platform dependent though and they can be quite big). This trick can be used to strongly optimize code where the bound is relatively big but you should avoid using it with huge bounds since the OS is free not to accept the virtual memory allocation (eg. in pathological cases like when the is no much memory left and there is no swap).

Comment: Thank you! So I should define everything using standard Python arrays then? Also, I did compile the Numba code using `.append` as you've suggested, it was not fast. In fact, it might have been slower than standard Python (I didn't time it, but looking at memory allocation, it certainly seemed slower).

Comment: In my past experiments, Numba lists was not much faster than the one of CPython, but never slower either (as long as you do not return the list from a Numba function). Still `append` should be faster than concatenation (it can be close if the two lists have the same size -- even possibly a bit faster in this specific case). Numba is mainly meant to speed up Numpy/numerical code, so not much lists (ie. it can be optimized but developers do not focus on this).